# How to integrate OpenGL and GLU in WinAPI application?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am interested in the task of creating an application using WinAPI, with the ability to use it in a window with OpenGL graphics, along with WinAPI elements.
 For example, to half of the window occupied by a window with graphics, and the second some elements of WinAPI.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to approach this is to create a child window for the OpenGL area. Create with `CS_OWNDC` class style and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` window style, so that there is a separate device context available and sibling windows (for buttons, etc.) can be placed on top of it on the Z-stack. The rest is initializing the pixelformat and OpenGL context as per usual, but on that child window.

1. `ChoosePixelFormat`
2. `SetPixelFormat`
3. `wglCreateContext`
4. `wglMakeCurrent`

Note that if you want modern OpenGL you also need a proxy OpenGL context, to retrieve the attribute based format selection functions. It's [described in detail](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)#Proper_Context_Creation) in the official OpenGL wiki.